# Library item "referencing" other content

Tags: 2010, document-library, lookup-column

Sorry for the nondescript title, it's a little hard to explain concisely.

We are setting up SharePoint 2010 to act as a simple document management system, to store documents such as forms, procedures, processes etc. They will be in standard Document Libraries, spread across various webs in the site collection.

Take the scenario of a form to request new mobile phone for an employee. That may reference some procedure document which describes how to determine what type of phone you need (loan, new phone, smart phone), and maybe some other forms to organise international roaming or additional equipment (extra batteries or some such thing).

The business wants to make this information available from SharePoint, so a user can easily see "here's my form for a new mobile phone, oh documents X, Y and Z are probably important for me to read too", and click link to go to those documents.

The referenced documents can exist in any library anywhere in the site collection, be of any content type, and can support zero, one or many referenced documents.

I have seen Document Sets, however they just seem to be for grouping files in the same library (almost like glorified folders).

I don't believe this is possible OOTB (short of simply having a multi-line text box in which to enter URLs, yuck), does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem with as little custom development as possible?

Thank you!

Edit: a quick mock up of what I'm thinking might look like is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xo1m.png. I can't embed in the post, because I don't have enough reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

I found some interesting column types included in the publishing feature:

- Hyperlink with formatting and constraints for publishing
- Summary Links data

The first looks great, but only accepts a single link.
Summary Links data looked even better (perhaps even overkill) but... it does't actually render anything except when loaded in the edit form!  ([assessment of the Summary Links Data column type](http://njbblog.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/sharepoint-40-summary-links-data-column.html)).

I've found a third party solution which seems to do the trick nicely, and doesn't cost the earth: [InfoWise Document Link Field](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/dl06.aspx?id=DocumentLinkField). Hopefully this will do!

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use Document Library? I mean you can use Custom List in which you can give them to write some details, title for request etc. and use List Attachments...

In that way you will have one entry for a single request but multiple documents can be attached for the request and you can then use workflows on this Custom List [if needed]

Comment: Sorry, I might not have explained clearly; I won't actually be storing requests, it's just a PDF/docx of a form/process/policy/etc that people either look at or, in the case of a form, print and fill out (yes, that's very backwards, we're putting in InfoPath/workflow later ;).

Comment: @DanielFlint can't think of any other solution :)

Comment: No worries, thanks anyway @Arsalan :) I suspect it's going to require either custom development or be part of a much more expansive solution (e.g. something from Bamboo) that would be absolutely overkill at this stage of the project.